# How to load textures to XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, so I need a texture for a game that I'm making and I found a texture that fit to my project(some kind of ball). The texture is next to other textures(Textures sheet).
So I had to download all the sheet. Now, I need to get only the texure that I want (that ball). And I can only circle it by a rectangle(using Paint). Is it true that XNA has an ignorant color? Or there's any other way that I can load ONLY MY BALL? and not the background of it?

Please, I really need an answer for it.. Thanks alot.

Comment: Add the texture containing only the ball and its background to your content project. Set the "Color Key" property of the file to the background that you want to be transparent. (don't have time to write more detailed answer).

Comment: @George How can I set the "Color Key" property? Where's it located at? How can it know the background of the texture?

Comment: One tips if you going to use a lot of own edited textures is to download paint.net. It works and looks similar to paint but have more features like "magic want" and "layers". But most important, if you in paint.net select a part of a texture and then press delete it dont become white...it becomes transparent and stays transparent when used in XNA =)

Answer (score 2):

To enable colour-key transparency, select your texture in your content project and press F4 to bring up the properties window. Expand the "Content Processor" option to reveal the colour key settings. Turn on colour key and select the appropriate colour.

If you need to use a sprite sheet within XNA (ie: if you're not cropping it in your image editor), you can use the `sourceRectangle` parameter to `SpriteBatch.Draw` to treat only a particular rectangular region of your source texture as a sprite.

By default `SpriteBatch` will draw with `BlendState.AlphaBlend` (ie: if you use the `Begin()` overload, you don't need to set it), which will correctly handle the transparency for you.

Comment: also download a tool like paint.net and crop your image to only contain the ones you want and potentially handle the transparency at the image level